# Нужно получить на c# исходный текст html страницы

Tags: c#, html

И на самом то деле задачка проста!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = GetCode("http://upakorel.ru/product-category/sv-valentin/");
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.Read();
    }
    public static String GetCode(string urlAddress)
    {
        //string urlAddress = "http://google.com";
        string data = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }
             data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Но вместо html я получаю

```html
<html><head><script>function set_cookie(){var now = new Date();var time = now.ge
tTime();time += 19360000 * 1000;now.setTime(time);document.cookie='beget=begetok
'+'; expires='+now.toGMTString()+'; path=/';}set_cookie();location.reload();;</s
cript></head><body></body></html>
```

То есть какой то яваскрипт что ли  - хз. Как мне получить настоящий исходный код страницы-как в браузере фаербагом.

Comment: Это и есть "Настоящий html" в браузере просморите исходный код страницы, отличатся не должно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем при первом запросе, т.к. у вас отсутствуют `Cookie` они вам устанавливаются с помощью `JavaScript`, нужно перед отправкой `request` установить их самостоятельно

```
string data = "";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

Cookie cookie = new Cookie
{
    Name = "beget",
    Value = "begetok"
};

request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(urlAddress), cookie);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то ли не устанавливаются - опять тот же результат

Comment: Я проверял и получил html страницы с каталогом

Comment: @LutiyCsharp, перепроверьте, код рабочий. Удостоверьтесь, что поместили вставку кук куда надо, перед вызовом `GetResponse`.

Comment: @LutiyCsharp добавил скриншот

Comment: Да заработало! Просто я ссылку Вам указал главную, а сам уже внутрь сайта полез. Вернул  на корневую и все гут!!! Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3):

Это настоящий HTML, сайт загружается в два захода. Первый раз выполняется скрипт JS, который проставляет куки `set_cookie()` и перезагружает страницу `location.reload()`. Когда вы пытаетесь получить страницу без перезагрузки, то никаких кук нет и перезагрузку с ними Вы не делаете.

Добавьте куки и будет Вам счастье.

```
if (request.CookieContainer == null)
{
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
}

request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(urlAddress), new Cookie("beget","begetok"));
```

Comment: ваш код не работает

Comment: @tCode, спасибо, поправил, из примера который подсмотрел.

Comment: все равно не работает `{"Параметр '{0}' не может быть пустой строкой.\r\nИмя параметра: cookie.Domain"}`

Comment: @tCode, да, действительно он требует первый аргумент, хотя в подсказках показывается конструктор с одним аргументом. Мне Ваш поспешный минус совсем не нравится, так хочется рейтинга на свой ответ?

Comment: попробовал, но все равно не помогает

Comment: @LutiyCsharp Вам не кажется что два правильных ответа работают у всех но не у вас, значит вы вставляете куки не туда куда надо. Обновите свой код, так будет легче найти ошибку